# Wrong filepath in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv, for-loop

I try to get all the csv files from my folder.

I did this with :

`currentfile = glob.glob("pathwheremycsvare')`

so in the variable `currentfile` there  is now a list of all pathnames of the csv files. (Currently there is only one file for testing.)

Now I try to put it to the `pandas.read_csv` function:

```
readcsv=pd.read_csv(currentfile)
```

But I get this exception:

```
ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'set'>
```

How can I fix this?

Edit:

tried: `path = r"pathname\*.csv"
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)`

It prints me all the csv files with the path.

now I need a foor loop, which executes the rest of the Programm with each csv.

I ll try it with a for loop...

Comment: Judging from the error message, I would expect `type(currentfile)` to return `set`. If so, you'll need to extract the string value of each path from `currentfile`. Easiest is probably just to iterate over `currentfile`.

Comment: Do you want to have one DataFrame containing the information from all files, or separate DataFrames, one for each of the files?

Comment: print what currentfile looks like. What you need to do is iterate through each one and read the individual csv's, and judging by your question append them all to one massive dataframe containing all of your data.

Comment: Assuming you want to combine all of the csv files into a single dataframe and they all have similar structure, try the following: `pd.concat([pd.read_csv(current_file) for current_file in os.listdir('pathwheremycsvare')])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned, `currentfile` is a list of all pathnames of the csv files.
And `pd.read_csv` takes file name to read file. Not a list of file names.
Like, `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`
Or you can iterate over `currentfile` 
Like

```
for file in currentfile:
   pd.read_csv(file)
```

Hope that helps!